# Python loop on list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in Python.

**Hello Admin:**

> Make a list of five or more usernames, including the name
>   'admin'. Imagine you are writing code that will print a greeting to each user after they log in to a website. Loop through the list, and print a greeting to each user:
>
> • If the username is 'admin', print a special greeting, such as Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?
>
> • Otherwise, print a generic greeting, such as Hello Eric, thank you for logging in again.

Code:

```
u = input('Enter Username: ').title()

for user in usernames:
    if u in user == 'Admin':
        print('Welcom admin')
        if u in user:
            print('In list')
    else:
        print('Not in list')
```

Comment: What's the code that you've used so far?

Comment: u = input('Enter Username: ').title()

for user in usernames:
    if u in user == 'Admin':
        print('Welcom admin')
        if u in user:
            print('In list')
    else:
        print('Not in list')

Comment: Edit your question to include any new informations (like your code) instead of burying it in the comment section. Dont forget to format it with markdown ;)

Comment: add that to your post/question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the question, you are looking for an answer

Create a list `user_names`(based on PEP 8 naming convention) and loop through them

```
user_names = ['eric', 'willie', 'admin', 'erin', 'ever']

for user in user_names:
    if user == 'admin':
        print("Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?")
    else:
        print("Hello " + user + ", thank you for logging in again!")
```

To see an answer as below

```
Hello eric, thank you for logging in again!
Hello willie, thank you for logging in again!
Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?
Hello erin, thank you for logging in again!
Hello ever, thank you for logging in again!
```

If you want to just ask for a name as input and print the output based on the provided input here's the code

```
user = input('Enter Username: ').lower()

if user == 'admin':
    print(f'Hello {user}, would you like to see a status report?')
else:
    print(f'Hello {user.title()}, thank you for logging in again.')
```

With a predefined list where you will be checking the user in the `user_name` list, here's the answer

```
user = input('Enter Username: ').lower()

user_names = ["eric", "admin", "lever", "matt"]

if user in user_names:
    if user == 'admin':
        print(f'Hello {user}, would you like to see a status report?')
    else: 
        print(f'Hello {user.title()}, thank you for logging in again.')

else:
    print('Not in list')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank-you very much you have defined in detail but i want to know that if we are checking user from predefined list then we  need a loop or not

Comment: i have done this by if else but if you see the question it is telling looping through the list

Comment: Anywhere if you are using `for...in` or `while`, it's a loop. Using a conditional like if...else doesn't have any impact as you are checking whether the user is an admin or not. To go through a list, you need a loop

Comment: but the above for loop code would print all values and i want if user input admin and other usernames and they are in list then in list else not in list

Comment: Check the last code-snippet above, it won't print all the users

Comment: it's still printing all the values i'm giving admin as user-input

Comment: Updated my answer with the output I am seeing after executing the last code-snippet in my answer

Comment: it's without for loop

Comment: As per your exercise question, it's never mentioned to ask for user input.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list in the form `users = [user1, user2, ...]`

Then iterate the users list with a `for` loop and insert an `if` statement to contol if the user in the user list is the "admin" user to change the greeting.

Comment: i have edited my question and post code on that i;m taking useriput how but loop is not breaking

Answer (score 1):

```
username = input('Enter Username: ').title()
```

Once the input is given:

```
for username in usernames:
    if username in usernames:
       if username == 'Admin'
          print("Hello admin, would you like to see a status report?")
       else:
          print("Hello " + username + ", thank you for logging in again.")
    else:
        print("You are not on the user's list")
```

This will loop through all the values in the array and if the value is equal to admin it will print a special message, otherwise a generic message :)

Comment: if i run the it print all names in the list

Comment: actually i'm taking a user-input u = input('Enter Username: ').title()

Comment: Taking your example, you would first need to check if the user is in the list. Once the user is in the list then you can check if it is admin or not. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is wrong. It should be:

```
for user in usernames:
    if user == 'admin':
        print(f'Hello {user}, would you like to see a status report?')
    else: 
        print(f'Hello {user}, thank you for logging in again.')
```

The above is without user input since what I understand that you are asked for is this. If you insist for user input:

```
u = input('Enter Username: ').title()

if u in usernames:
    if u == 'admin':
        print(f'Hello {u.lower()}, would you like to see a status report?')
    else: 
        print(f'Hello {u()}, thank you for logging in again.')

else:
    print('Not in list')
```

Also, for efficiency reasons you could consider converting the list into a set with `usernames = set(usernames)`.

Comment: I have edited my answer switching `.lower()` with `.title()`. Could you try again?

Comment: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: i have remove lower() this and now the code is running fine

Comment: can you answer me one more thing

Comment: what the difference between if u in  user == 'Admin': and if u == 'admin':